# CollectionView didSelectItemAt did not activate in some simulators (e.g. iPad Pro 12.9 inch)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I cant figure out the following issue: I made a menu that should be usable for multiple apple devices. I tested it in several simulators of xcode (now 14.2). Some simulators work well but not all.

For example the simulators wil not activate the didSelectItemAt in the CollectionView:

- iPad Air (4th generation- iOS 14.2) - 1180.0, 820.0
- iPad 10th generation - iOS 16.2
- iPad Pro 11.0 inch (2th gen) (iOS 14.2) 1194.0, 834.0
- iPad Pro 12.9 inches 1366.0, 1024.0
- The layout of the menu looks oke en works fine.

In didSelectItemAt works fine in the simulators:

- iPhone 11 Pro
- iPhone 12 - iOS 14.2 - 844.0, 390.0
- iPad Air 2 - iOS 14.2 - 1024.0, 768.0
- iPad (6th generation - iOS 16.2) 1024.0, 768.0
- iPad (9th generation - iOS 16.2) 1080.0, 810.0
- iPad Pro (9,7 inch - iOS 14.4) 1024.0, 768.0

I found that in the Debug ViewHierachy there is a difference between e.g. ipad Air 2 and ipad 11 Pro.
By the iPad 11 Pro there is an extra UIView added that I can't explain. I think this falls over the  items.  The reason i think why i cant select the items when use e.q. iPad 11 Pro. But I don't know how to adjust this. (See also the images).

iPad Air 2

[image: iPad Air 2]

iPad 11 Pro

[image: iPad 11 Pro]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Instead of modifying view.frame it worked by modifying superview.frame. Apparently this is necessary for the higher models of iPads and iPhones.

```
   // animate the gamescene to view of close the mainmenu.
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: ({
        self.gameBackgroundView?.superview?.frame = CGRect(x:slideToXPosition,
                                                           y:0,
                                                           width: frameSize!.width,
                                                           height: frameSize!.height)

        
    })) { _ in
      
        completion?()
    }
```